# Does the stdlib provide a type list?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, std

In modern C++, does the standard library provide a type list template?

```
int main() {
    using int_types = type_list<int,long,short,char>;
    std::cout << length<int_types>::value << ' '
              << typeid(element<2,int_types>::type).name();
}
```

Note that `int_types` does not store any values (as `std::tuple` does). It's merely a list of types.

Comment: Presumably `std::tuple` won't do because `int_types` objects are created at some point? It's implied by your remark, just want to clarify that point.

Comment: Short answer: no, long answer: nyet :-) Perhaps if you indicated *what* you wanted to do (rather than *how*), we could assist more. In other words, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Why not use an `std::tuple` which you never need to instantiate? `tuple_size` and `tuple_element` let you query the type list at compile time.

Comment: @interjay: Because sometimes (for example, when picking overloaded functions) I might have to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did something like this:

```
template<typename ...T> struct type_list {};

template<typename    L> struct length;
template<typename ...T> struct length<type_list<T...>> {static const std::size_t value=sizeof...(T);};

template<std::size_t I, typename L>
struct element;
template<typename F, typename ...T> 
struct element<0, type_list<F, T...>> {using type=F;};
template<std::size_t I> 
struct element<I, type_list<>>        {using type=void;};
template<std::size_t I, typename F, typename ...T> 
struct element<I, type_list<F, T...>> {using type=typename element<I-1,type_list<T...>>::type;};

int main() {
    using int_types = type_list<int,long,short,char>;
    std::cout << length<int_types>::value << '\n'
              << typeid(element<2,int_types>::type).name() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that, in modern C++ standard library, nearest what you want is `std::tuple`.

If the problem is that `std::tuple` store values of the listed types (so, I suppose, can be a problem instantiate an object of that type) it's easy write a instantiable object that wraps a `std::tuple` `using` without instantiate the `std::tuple` itself.

I mean... given a wrapper like this

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct wrapTuple
 {
   using type = std::tuple<Ts...>;

   template <std::size_t N>
   using element = std::tuple_element_t<N, type>;

   static constexpr auto length { std::tuple_size_v<type> };
 };
```

you can write the following lines without instantiate the wrapper

```
   using int_types = wrapTuple<int, long, short, char>;

   std::cout << int_types::length << ' '
      << typeid(int_types::element<2u>).name() << std::endl;
```

but you can also instantiate it without instantiate the `std::tuple`

```
   int_types it;

   std::cout << it.length << ' '
      << typeid(decltype(it)::element<2u>).name() << std::endl;
```

Comment: While this works (`+1`), it is an ugly workaround that requires documentation in order for others to understand it. I might just use my own type list template then. Those are easy to understand and good naming gets the purpose across without need for extensive documentation for the intent.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::tuple` type but don't instantiate it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    using int_types = std::tuple<int, long, short, char>;
    std::cout << std::tuple_size_v<int_types> << ' '
        << typeid(std::tuple_element_t<2, int_types>).name();
}
```

MSVC output:

```
4 short
```

GCC output:

```
4 s
```

Clang output:

```
4 s
```

Comment: Not sure but I suspect that the OP prefer `std::tuple_element_t` instead of `std::tuple_element`.

Comment: @max66 yes, I think so. Thanks for pointing out, it makes more sense now

Comment: I could use tuple (`+1`), but I'd need to wrap it like max66 showed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56618573/140719), because sometimes (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56618301/does-the-stdlib-provide-a-type-list#comment99824889_56618301) I might have to instantiate it.